# split row to create header in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` like:

```
age=14  gender=male     loc=NY  key=0012328434    Unnamed: 4
age=45  gender=female   loc=CS  key=834734hh43    pre="axe"
age=23  gender=female   loc=CA  key=545df35fdf    NaN
..
..
age=65  gender=male     loc=LA  key=dfdf545dfg    pre="cold"
```

And I need this df to have a header and remove the redundant data, like `desired_df`:

```
age     gender          loc     key             pre
14      male            NY      0012328434      NaN
45      female          CS      834734hh43      axe
23      female          CA      545df35fdf      NaN
..
..
65      male            LA      dfdf545dfg      cold
```

what I tried to do:

```
df1 = df.str.split()
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df1.str[1::2].tolist(), columns=df1[0][0::2])
```

but this fails, clearly as I do not have a df name to begin with. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist editing the question with what I tried

Comment: There's no question here to begin with, so I'm glad you're editing it.

Comment: I'm curious where the dataframe actually comes from. From some CSV file that thinks it's a JSON file?

Comment: Perhaps just `.str.removeprefix` with the appropriate prefixes, and add the column headers manually? Probably easiest to create a list of the headers, and run `.str.removeprefix` in a loop over the column names.

Comment: Why is there a "pre" in the last column for the desired output? And what happens to "Unnamed: 4"? The latter appears to be a column header, but it is in a row instead of a header.

Comment: @9769953 it would fail since the files could have different headers and also the list would have to store n number of predefined headers

Comment: What about my questions about "pre" and "Unnamed: 4"?

Comment: @9769953 that is because the Unnamed:4 should be discarded and the first value found in the column should be the header i.e. `pre`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# df = pd.read_csv(r'xyz.csv', header = None)

df1=(pd.DataFrame(df.fillna('NaN=NaN')
         .apply(lambda x: dict(list(x.str.replace('"', '')
                          .str.split('='))), axis=1).to_list())
       .drop('NaN', axis = 1))


  age  gender loc         key     pre
0  14    male  NY  0012328434     
1  45  female  CS  834734hh43     axe
2  23  female  CA  545df35fdf     NaN
3  65    male  LA  dfdf545dfg    cold
```

Comment: Getting error: `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Comment: and also this `df[df == 'NaN'] = 'NaN:NaN'` gives me: `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Comment: cool. now the whole chunk like `df = df.to_dict()
df[df == 'NaN'] = 'NaN:NaN'
pd.DataFrame(df.fillna('NaN:NaN')
  .apply(lambda x: dict(list(x.str.replace('"', '')
                              .str.split('[:=]'))), axis=1).to_list()).drop('NaN', axis = 1)` gives me: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fillna'`

Comment: apologies, since the data has n number of columns it'll be hard to paste it in the question, here is the file: http://sendanywhe.re/ZI7R1XZV

Comment: Getting: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #8 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: @jacktry again this time round it should work

Comment: @jack does it still not work?

Comment: it works fine but just takes a lot of time, is there anyway to take less time?

Comment: @jack How big is your data? The one you shared runs under a second

Comment: it was a sample data, the actual one has millions of records.